# I'm really having trouble with "but" (as in "except") in this phrase

Tags: syntax, preposition

I'm trying to say "No one but [i.e. except] love provokes me with impunity." where *love* is a metonymic stand-in for *the person I love*. I hope it makes sense. (You can read it as a personification if it makes things easier.)

Here's what I've come up with so far:

> Nemo nisi amor me impune lacessit.

This seems wrong, though. A little help?

Comment: As for nemo+nisi, it doesn't seem wrong to me, see Cic. Pis. 7, [English](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Cic.+Pis.+7&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0020), [Latin](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0013%3Atext%3DPis.%3Asection%3D7). Is that your only concern?

Comment: @Rafael Mostly. I As Draconis points out below, the unless/except ambiguity was also something I was wondering about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rafael points out in the comments, the pattern *nēmō nisi* is attested Classically, though personally I would use *nisi quam amō* or the like rather than *nisi amor*. To use Rafael's example, from [Cicero's *In Pisonem* 7](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0013%3Atext%3DPis.%3Asection%3D7):

> *…ut nemo, **nisi qui mecum esset**, civium esse in numero videretur.*
>   …that nobody seemed to be among the citizens, **unless they were with me**.

*Nisi* literally means "unless", so it needs to be followed by a full verbal phrase. Your *nisi amor* is perfectly valid, as a shorthand for *nisi quī est amor*, but the full phrase sounds better to me.

If you want a word for "except" which is followed by a noun, I would use *praeter*. The "except" meaning is more common in Later Latin, but also shows up in Classical times. For instance, from Cicero's *Letters to his Brother Quintus* 1.1.5:

> *…etiam e Graecis ipsis diligenter cavendae sunt quaedam familiaritates, **praeter hominum perpaucorum**…*
>   And even from the Greeks themselves, certain intimacies must be carefully guarded against, **except those of a very few people**…

Interestingly, *praeter* with this meaning can be either an adverb or a preposition taking the accusative. So for your sentence, I would say:

> *Nēmō praeter Amorem mē impūnē lacessit.*
>   Nobody except Love provokes me with impunity.

Comment: While *praeter* can be an adverb, in this context I think it should definitely be treated as a preposition (*praeter Amorem*). Every [example of *nemo praeter* in Cicero](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=nemo+praeter) uses it with the accusative.

Comment: @brianpck Fixed

Comment: @Draconis Yes, I do think that _praeter_ works much better. I hadn't even considered it, but it does effectively eliminate that ambiguity that I'd also been concerned about. Thanks for this! :)